# Transition Between Background Images Declared in HTML CSS tag

Tags: jquery, css

I can change my background image with:

```
 $('html').css({background : 'url(http://www.cyberth.com/images/background_aporia.jpg)'});
```

How can I have a fade out and fade in transition between the two images. If I can avoid it I don't want to use div's inside Body for this.

something like this does not seem to work:

```
 $('html').not('body').fadeOut("slow");
```

Setting the opacity on the html tag also cascades down even when I change the z index of html to 1 and body to 2.

My background declaration in css looks like this:

```
 html { 
     background: url(http://www.cyberth.com/images/background_odonata.jpg) 
     no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: opacity is `inherited` to children automatically, and will affect all children, since your `body` is a child of `html` it will `inherit` it's opacity and nothing you can do can change that :) unless you use a sprite background image (png with a range of opacity) :) then animate the `backgroun-position` if you could :)

Comment: can I use any jquery animations to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 1):

You could not apply the background to the html, but to a div with position absolute with 100% width and height with negative z-index. Then you should be abled to do any kind of stuff to that div without affecting anything else. You then even could use a plugin like jquery cycle for that. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/